# How to use PigDump() in Pig?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig, dump

I am trying to store data using PigDump() and am getting the following error.

```
grunt> TxtLdr = load '/wordcountdata.txt' using TextLoader();
grunt> STORE TxtLdr into '/pigdmpOP' using PigDump();       

2014-07-30 19:59:39,102 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve PigDump using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
Details at logfile: /home/Xperttech/pig-0.12.0/pig_1406764753800.log
```

I am getting the error irrespective of the Loading storage method I use (TextLoader / PigStorage / BinaryStorage) and irrespective of the target directory (hdfs or local system)

The log file has the following data:

> ERROR 1070: Could not resolve PigDump using imports: [, java.lang.,
>   org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
>
> Failed to parse: Pig script failed to parse:  pig
>   script failed to validate:
>   org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 1070:
>   Could not resolve PigDump using imports: [, java.lang.,
>   org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
>       at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:196)
>       at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.validateQuery(PigServer.java:1648)
>       at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1621)
>       at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:575)
>       at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processPig(GruntParser.java:1093)
>       at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:501)
>       at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:198)
>       at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
>       at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:69)
>       at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:541)
>       at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160) Caused by:  pig script failed to validate:
>   org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 1070:
>   Could not resolve PigDump using imports: [, java.lang.,
>   org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
>       at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.validateFuncSpec(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:1260)
>       at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildFuncSpec(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:1245)
>       at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.func_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:5069)
>       at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.store_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:7667)
>       at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.op_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1580)
>       at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.general_statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1013)
>       at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:553)
>       at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.query(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:421)
>       at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:188)
>       ... 15 more Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 1070:
>   Could not resolve PigDump using imports: [, java.lang.,
>   org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
>       at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.resolveClassName(PigContext.java:653)
>       at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.validateFuncSpec(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:1257)
>       ... 23 more

Can you suggest what am I doing wrong? Are any files needed to be imported before trying to implement PigDump() ? (If so, how?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show me your input data?

Comment: Can you say for what input it works?
As, I have tried for different types of .txt with and without ',' delimiter and newline delimiter.

Comment: @Rengasamy - When I do 
'dump TxtLdr;' 
the output I get is
(Apache Hadoop is an open-source software framework for storage and large-scale processing of data-sets on clusters of commodity hardware. Hadoop is an Apache top-level project being built and used by a global community of contributors and users.[2] It is licensed under the Apache License 2.0.)

Comment: Did you get that message in the grunt shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm affraid the documentation is not completely up to date. `PigDump` was removed in the 0.7 release.
This is stated [here](http://wiki.apache.org/pig/Pig070IncompatibleChanges) :

> We have also removed org.apache.pig.builtin.BinaryStorage loader/store function and org.apache.pig.builtin.PigDump which were only used from within streaming. They can be restored if needed - we would just need to implement the corresponding Input/OutputFormats.

Answer (score 1):

PigDump was removed but for your purposes, PigStorage will work.

Change:

```
`STORE TxtLdr into '/pigdmpOP' using PigDump();`
```

to:

```
`STORE TxtLdr into '/pigdmpOP' using PigStorage(',');`
```